# want to update google sheets from a streaming database...data has to be readily available for querying/reporting

Tags: google-sheets, import, db2, export, cloud

querying a student database with columns in google sheets.  currently the data is updated overnight but want to change the source to a streaming source so that data is more dynamic, more current reflecting reality versus 'yesterday's news'.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough details for a specific answer. Google Sheets has an API you can use for reading and updating data ([Java sample, for example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java)), and depending on your source of data you might have a built-in integration.